# Implementing Data Layout Optimizations in the LLVM Framework

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Does anyone know the source path to the relevant pass in the video? I have searched for a long time without finding.
link:[2014 LLVM Developers’ Meeting: “Implementing Data Layout Optimizations in LLVM Framework ”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ckzole3hArc)

Comment: The code they committed is in the LLVM git repo, logged with their names.

Comment: could you give me a link?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. But if you want I'll explain how I'd use a shell pipeline involving `git log` or `git blame` to approach this kind of problem. SO is for learning to do things, see? If you want someone else to do them for you, try mturk.com instead.

Comment: ok, thank you very much!

Comment: They talk in the video that this project involves proprietary information, so I'm guessing they may not have made the source code public.